# ASPX VS CSHTML to do grid processing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I need to write a web page which I need to interact with Grid entry/edit.
I choose ASP.Net MVC and LINQ TO Entity Framework.

What my problem is I have two option to choose at View Layer.

1. ASPX
2. Razor CSHTML

Could someone please give me suggestion which one is more suitable to interact Grid Entry Edit process? 
And Why?

If there are any references , please let me see them also.

**[UPDATED]**

- [JQUERY Grid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=883)
- [Telerik Grid for ASP.NET MVC](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid)
- [Razor Web Grid](http://www.w3schools.com/razor/razor_webgrid.asp)

After I searching through at Google, I get more than one Grid Controls.
I still wondering which one I need to use.
When I was writing with net 2.0 framework, I use template control from GridView Control in traditional way to put Combo or some other controls to attatch with GridView.It is really useful.

So What i thinking is, at asp net MVC 3 version, should i also use these traditional technique as well.

Could anyone please give me suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Razor is simply more concise. Both Razor and WebForms will offer the same basic functionality, but Razor results in Views that are much less cluttered and therefore more easily understood.

Answer (score 2):

View engines have nothing to do with this.  They both provide the same functionality, which you use is up to you and your preference.

There are many kinds of grids available for MVC, but MVC itself does not come with a grid.  You either have to build the grid yourself, or use a third party component, most of which are jQuery based.  Again, it's up to you what to use, as it's your preference.

All you can do is choose something and go with it.  If it doesn't work for you, choose something else.  MVC is a technology that requires you to know much more about how the framework works.  If you want point and click and drag and drop, you should go back to Web Forms.

Answer (score 2):

.chtm provides "Mapping of Data(or Business) objects that Your UI needs to Render(the html)" in a isolated way, so you can control the Test Cases for your UI as well as your Business Object Unit testing, which is Hard using ASPX since you have to create HTTPContext and (SSL and all crap) just to TEST your Business Logic..in short .cshmt is more NEATLY TESTABLE than aspx.